# Using pairs on the lines iterator

Tags: nim-lang

is there a more elegant way to do this? I would like to use `for iLine, line in lines inputFile`, so the sugar for `pairs`. However that doesn't seem to work with the `lines` iterator. Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?

```py
var iLine = 0
for line in lines inputFile:
    for iCell, cell in line:
        var val = false
        if cell == '#':
            val = true

        row[iCell] = val
    
    map[iLine] = row
    iLine += 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`enumerate`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/enumerate.html) iterator like this:

```
import std / enumerate

for lnum, line in enumerate(lines inputFile):
  # Do your thing here.
```

This iterator was introduced in Nim v1.4.0, so make sure your version is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just define `pairs` for `File`, so you could write

```
iterator pairs(f: File): (int, string) =
  var idx = 0
  for line in lines(f):
    yield (idx, line)
    inc idx

for idx, line in open("/tmp/a.nim"):
  echo idx
```

It might be a little ambiguous - e.g. `lines` one clearly shows that you are iterating over indexed lines. Second alternative is to return `(int, string)` from iterator:

```
iterator idxLines(f: string): (int, string) =
  var idx = 0
  for line in lines(open(f)):
    yield (idx, line)
    inc idx

for idx, line in idxLines("/tmp/a.nim"):
  echo idx
```